# Why does the emulator perform so many writes?

Tags: linux, android-emulator, performance

I'm using the Android Emulator from IntelliJ on Kubuntu. I noticed in plasma-systemmonitor that qemu-system-x86_64 continuously does on the order of a few MB/s of disk writes even as I'm not using the emulator at all, it's just open. Sometimes it goes below 1 MB/s, sometimes up to a few dozen MB/s.

Is this level of activity normal? I'm starting to wonder if this amount of writes can shorten the life of my SSD if I leave it running all the time. Or could it be another type of writes that are not disk writes? I'm not 100% sure what plasma-systemmonitor measures.

I'm emulating a Pixel 4 with Google Play.

Comment: You should check which files those write operations are applied to (e.g. using inotify-tools or similar). May be it is simply some log file which is updated very often but not directly written to disk by the OS.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use inotify-tools for this. lsof doesn't show much in terms of files potentially being written to but shows a number of "pipe" and "type=STREAM" lines so maybe it's just interprocess communication.